# Passing an std::array as an argument in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to pass an `std::array` as an argument to a function, and I cannot find the correct way.

I am not talking about normal C array (e.g. `int arr[2]={1,3};`).
I am talking about `std::array` class, available from C++ 11.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

class test
{
   void function(array<int> myarr)
   {
      // .......some code..........
   }
};
```

How do I pass an `std::array` to a function, as `std::array` takes two template arguments: `std::array<class T, std::size_t N>`, but while passing it as an argument I do not want to specify the size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not knowing the second template argument to `std::array<>` means your `test` class should be templated as well.

```
template <std::size_t N>
class test
{
    void function(const std::array<int, N> & myarr)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

By the way, it's better to pass `myarr` as `const &`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an approach like:

```
#include<array>
using namespace std;

template <size_t N>
class test
{
    void function(const array<int, N> & myarr)
    {
        /* My code */
    }
};
```

But keep in mind that `std::array` is not a dynamic array. You have to know the sizes at compile time.

If you get to know the sizes later at runtime of your program you should consider using `std::vector` instead:

```
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class test
{
    void function(const vector<int> & myvec)
    {
        /* My code */
    }
};
```

In that variant you don't need to pass the size at all.